# how to get an observable as output instead of object in route resolve

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing

`resolve: {course: ResolveService }` // This gives an object in return. Instead get an observable. Is it possible?

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'registration',
      component: SomeComponent,
      canDeactivate: [SomeGuardService],
      resolve: {course: ResolveService } // This gives an object in retrun
     },
```

// resolve

```
@Injectable()
export class ResolveService implements Resolve<Observable<any>> {

  constructor(private dropDown: DropDownService) { }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
    return this.dropDown.coursesDt;
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the type of `courseDt`?

Comment: type is Observable

Comment: So you want to the resolve to return an `Observable<Observable<any>>`?

Comment: no i just tried to return an observable

Comment: can you update the answer with my code?

Comment: i just want the resolve to return an observable so that i can use async pipe on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `ResolveService` modify the `resolve` to return an observable of an observable. The resolve function will wait until the returned observable emits and then bind that to the value defined in the route config. In order to send an observable to the route component you will need to wrap it in another observable. Like so:

```js
@Injectable()
export class ResolveService implements Resolve<Observable<any>> {

    constructor(private dropDown: DropDownService) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Observable<any>> {
        return Observable.of(this.dropDown.coursesDt);
    }
}
```

Comment: So in Before `someObject` is just returned to the route as an object but in the After it is wrapped in an `Observable`. You did not post your `ResolveService` so I assumed the resolve method is just returning an object.

Comment: what does `Obeservable.of()` do

Comment: It makes an observable sequence that immediately emits the values that are passed to it. [Observable.of](https://github.com/btroncone/learn-rxjs/blob/master/operators/creation/of.md)